# SIP API Error - QGIS Noosa

Tags: qgis, python, sip

I have QGIS Noosa installed on two separate PCs working on Xubuntu. Both the PCs are configured for the same QGIS repository.

However, on one of the PCs, I have the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/__init__.py", line 80, in 
    import qgis.gui   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/gui/__init__.py", line 27, in 
    from qgis._gui import * RuntimeError: the sip module implements API v12.0 to v12.4 but the qgis._gui module requires API v12.5
```

I have already tried the following:

1. Doing a complete purge of the qgis software, and reinstallation.
2. Cleaning pip cache and reinstallation, both for Python versions 3.x and 2.x

How can this issue be rectified?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue. For me, it was a conflict between local pip installation and system wide installation.

With pyqt5 install via pip:

```py
>>> import PyQt5
>>> PyQt5.__file__
'/home/samuel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyQt5/__init__.py'
```

Then, when installed system wide

```py
>>> import PyQt5
>>> PyQt5.__file__
'/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyQt5/__init__.py'
```

And apparently, the sip API is not the correct one with pip installation.

What I did :

- uninstall qgis
- remove sip installed from pip : `python -m pip uninstall PyQt5-sip PyQt5`
- install system wide python-pyqt5 (I am using archlinux) : `sudo pacman -S python-pyqt5`
- reinstall qgis